# SCSS - Get container width as height

Tags: css, sass

Is there a way to get the container width of a child element in calculation of the child element height without using JavaScript.

Say, rendering an image in an 16:9px aspect ratio which is 1.778 : 1px.
If i set the image width to 100% of the container. How do i set the height to

PSEUDO:

```
$width: 100%;
height: (100% * 0.5625)px;
```

I'm trying to get the value of 100% using `calc()`, but doesn't work.

```
calc(100% + 1)px;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found it. Sass interpolation does the work. Its possible to use sass interpolation to reference a sibling property.

```
.container {
  width: 100%;

  img {
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(#{width} * 1.778);
  }
}
```

Comment: Didn't know you could interpolate properties that way in Sass. Couldn't really make it work, please take a look if you can! https://codepen.io/ophirbucai/pen/abxpEax

Answer (score 0):

No you cant get the width of 100% in px you hava to write in percent

```
width : 100%;
height: calc((100% * 16)/9);
```

Comment: Using 100% in `calc` for the calculation of height will use the percentage height of the container and not the percentage width of the container.