# Sass interpolation container height

Tags: html, css, sass

i have to use container height for width of child element.i found this thread [SCSS - Get container width as height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47496247/scss-get-container-width-as-height)

so in accepted answer he used sibling width and code snippet is

```
.container {
  width: 100%;

  img {
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(#{width} * 1.778);
  }
}
```

so i write a similar snippet

```
.banner1{
    .oval{
        min-width: calc(#{height});
    }
}
```

but this snippet is not working as shown in screenshot(https://monosnap.com/file/GnFSJbZ4ZJXCsOdtZZGxs08LImpl0J).
i want to know how to use height of container in sass and make it work

Comment: Do you have a variable for `height`?

Comment: The referenced SO post has explicit values set for `width: 100%` in both the container and the item itself. I don't see those here, although the screenshot does suggest you have `height:100%` for `.oval`. Do you have that for both `.oval` and `.banner1`?

Comment: yes i have that for both .oval and .banner1