# "npm run build" failed in React app due to calc(width) in css?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm building a React app that has progress bars from Bootstrap.

```html
<div className="progress">
  <div className="progress-bar"
    role="progressbar"
    aria-valuenow="60"
    aria-valuemin="0"
    aria-valuemax="100"
    style={{ width: "60%" }}
  />
</div>
```

and CSS

```css
.progress {
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #9c9c9c; }

.progress-bar {
  height: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
  animation: animated-progress 3s ease-out; }

@keyframes animated-progress {
  from {
    width: 0; }
  to {
    width: calc(width); } }
```

This is the complete code in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-night-33636?file=/src/styles.css:47-54)

I got the idea of using `calc(width)` to get element's width from this StackOverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47496247/scss-get-container-width-as-height)

It's working fine during development. However, when I run the command `npm run build` for production, I got the following error

```
Lexical error on line 1: Unrecognized text.
  Erroneous area:
1: width
^..^
CompileError: Begins at CSS selector undefined


npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! personal-site@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the personal-site@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

I know this error is caused by `calc(width)`, because I was able to build if I changed from `calc(width)` to `calc(60%)`. As you may realize, doing something like `calc(60%)` is not a good  approach to hard code the width.

Answer (score 1):

The error says it all. `width` is not recognized, i.e., it doesn't exist. That's why it works when you pass in a value. If you want to use a [css variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties), you have to declare it.

`width: calc(width);` is basically, `width:calc(undefined);`

Also, hard-coding the width isn't necessarily a bad thing. As with most things in programming, *it depends*.

### Edit

Passing in a value to calc doesn't make any sense. calc is useful for calculating expressions, e.g., `calc (50% - 10px)`. If you're going to pass in a percentage, just set the percentage.

### Response to comment

I don't believe it's working as you suggest, but that it's not bombing your page. In your sandbox, I did this:

```
@keyframes animated-progress {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: calc(thisDoesNotActuallyWork);
  }
}
```

and the page looked the same way. No console errors, no white screen -- it looked like this:

[image]

which is what it looked like when `width` was used.

I reassure you that if you don't declare a variable and set it to something, code tends to not work. How it fails depends, though.

Comment: as I mentioned in my post, `calc(width)` **does** work in development environment, but it fails when I create a production build of my app via `npm run build` command. If I hard code the percentage, then I have to do that for each of the progress bars I have.

Answer (score 0):

In the SO link you posted, they're referring to Sass which uses variables and interpolation like this:

```
$width: 100%;
height: calc(#{$width} * 1.778);
```

However, that post doesn't use the correct syntax, i.e., declaring variables with a `$` at the start, so I can see where you got confused.

With CSS you can declare variables with a different syntax:

```
--width: 100%;
height: calc(var(--width) * 1.778);
```

Though, it's worth noting:

> ...that the selector given to the ruleset defines the scope that the custom property can be used in. A common best practice is to define custom properties on the :root pseudo-class, so that it can be applied globally across your HTML document

So you could define the variable globally and it's easier to maintain if used in other parts of your CSS:

```
:root {
  --width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: calc(#{width}) in SASS is compiled to calc(width) in CSS. If you take a look at my CodeSandbox link in my post, `calc(width)` works fine. I can't use CSS variables since progress bars have different widths, e.g. 60%, 75%

Comment: `calc(width)` isn't valid CSS. I think the issue is that keyframes with a `from` value works by itself. So in development your `to` value is being ignored, but when you go to run the build, React doesn't know what `width` is referring to and so throw an error